# 99@99.com is it a valid email ID?

Tags: asp.net, regex

i am using `\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*` regex to validate email id in my

asp.net web application and this regular expression is provided by **visual studio 2010**

in their regular expression validator but if i entered 99@99.com then it is not showing any

error message.

so i just want to confirm that is it a valid email id?

Comment: What makes you think this wouldn't be a valid email? The domain exists and thus by definition means the domain is valid. After that it's up to the owner to create alias/POP accounts and they can be whatever he or she desires.

Comment: @Aaron Mclver,i completly agree whatever you said but the question comes because one of my person raise an issue that an email id cannot be numeric one so 99@99.com is just an example i am not specific to this one.

Comment: why -1 i am just curious about the correcr format of email ID i am not specific to 99@99.com it's just an example i already explained in my previous comment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's valid. [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321) and [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (section [3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1) specifically) define the local and domain parts of the email address, and both of them allow digits in any position.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address) has some more details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes off course is valid, actually the domain 99.com exits!

Comment: bet365.com is another kid on the block

Answer (score 0):

```
func isValidEmail(testStr: String) -> Bool {
    print("valid Email-ID: \(testStr)")
    let emailRegEx = "[A-Za-z0-9_%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@",emailRegEx)
    return emailTest.evaluateWithObject(testStr)
}
```

Comment: A short explanation is always recommended along with the code. Especially in this case, since he asked something specific which you did not answer...